# DUAL MODE SPI Linux Subsystem Support

Tags: linux-kernel

Does the Linux SPI subsystem have support for handling the slave side of SPI interactions?

The mechanism has two devices(devA running on Linux platform board and devB on another platform) glued together via 2 spi buses. The idea is to use one SPI bus when devA acts a master and to use the other bus to handle the return path data from the devB.

Does the Linux SPI subsystem support handling the devB as a slave device during the return data path?

Comment: What SPI slave device are you using?

Comment: I'm afraid that your question isn't very clear. SPI is a four-wire interface with a return data path built into it.  To ask if Linux can read a return data path is like asking if Linux supports SPI at all.  Are you really trying to ask if Linux can act as a slave to an external master?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am trying to configure my device as a slave SPI device to read data from an external master .

Comment: The slave device is an Inova UM_INAP375R chip on an i.mX6 board.